# Autoflush error and filter_by() query giving unexpected result

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My goal is to read data off of an excel sheet and create a database on a SQL server. I am trying to write a sample code using SQLalchemy and I am new to it. The code that I have so far is:

```
import time
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Date, String, Table, MetaData,table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo = False)

Base = declarative_base()

class blc(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'BLC_Databse'

    date = Column(String, primary_key = True)
    RES = Column(String)
    BTTLCOLUMN = Column(String)
    CS_HR = Column(Integer)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

sample = blc(date=time.strftime("%m/%d/%y") , RES = 'BDY_21', BTTLCOLUMN = '2075', CS_HR = 563) 

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

sample2 = blc(date=time.strftime("%m/%d/%y") , RES = 'BDY_21', BTTLCOLUMN = '2076', CS_HR = 375)

session.add(sample2)

session.commit()

with session.no_autoflush:
    result = session.query(blc).filter_by(RES = 'BDY_21').first()
    print(result)
```

When I am performing a filter query (which I am assuming it is similar to where clause in SQL) it gives  `<__main__.blc object at 0x00705770>` error
Eventually, I plan to have the insert clause on a loop and it will read data from an excel sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result is an object that references the class blc. To get the desired column, I had to do `result.ColName`.